# How to export only the output in pdf in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, jupyter-notebook, export, export-to-pdf

I have a notebook with one cell of code and one output. I would like to know how to export to pdf only the output and not the code.

The answers I found on internet provide only solution to export all the notebook.

Do you have any ideas how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
jupyter nbconvert --no-input --to pdf himekami.ipynb
```

Note the --no-input modifier. It will remove your code from the output.